Salesforce LWC: Total Quantity Not Updating Consistently in Shopping Cart Component
Add an Item: Add an address to a specific item in the shopping cart.
Enter Quantity: Enter a quantity for that item using the provided input field.
Observe Total Quantity: Notice that the total quantity field updates correctly to reflect the new quantity.
Repeat Steps: Change the quantity for the same item multiple times (4 to 5 times).
Issue Occurrence: After several updates, the total quantity field sometimes stops updating and retains a previous value instead of reflecting the new quantity.
below is the JS Code:
 `updateQuantity(event) {
    console.log("onchange - entered updateQuantity event handler------->")

    this.shippingAddressId = event.target.dataset.id;
    this.posItemId = event.target.dataset.pos;

    this.quantityUpdateValue = event.target.value;
    console.log("onchange - this.quantityUpdateValue------->",this.quantityUpdateValue);

    this.orderId = event.target.dataset.order;
    var posItemsListWithCart = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.posItemsListInCart))
    // console.log('posItemsListWithCart--->',JSON.stringify(posItemsListWithCart))
    for (var i = 0; i < posItemsListWithCart.length; i++) {
        var individualQty = 0;
        // Author: Shilpa and Kavya
        // Date: 19-12-2023
        // To get the Logical_Inventory__c from POS_Item_Facilities__r
        for(var z=0;z<posItemsListWithCart[i].posItem.POS_Item_Facilities__r.length;z++){
        var currentAvailableStock = posItemsListWithCart[i].posItem.POS_Item_Facilities__r[z].Logical_Inventory__c;
        }
        // Changes done upto here
        for (var j = 0; j < posItemsListWithCart[i].selectedAddressWithQtyDetails.length; j++) {
            if (this.shippingAddressId == posItemsListWithCart[i].selectedAddressWithQtyDetails[j].selectedAddress.Id) {
                let quantityTobeUpdated = event.target.value;

                this.quantityUpdateValue = quantityTobeUpdated == '' ? 0 : quantityTobeUpdated;
                console.log("onchange - checking if it is empty or not ----------> ",this.quantityUpdateValue)


                posItemsListWithCart[i].selectedAddressWithQtyDetails[j].quantity = this.quantityUpdateValue;
                console.log("onchange - to update the quantity in the data structure ----------> ",posItemsListWithCart[i].selectedAddressWithQtyDetails[j].quantity)
            }

            // after getting the qunity to calculate the totla quntity
            var quantity = posItemsListWithCart[i].selectedAddressWithQtyDetails[j].quantity == '' ? 0 : posItemsListWithCart[i].selectedAddressWithQtyDetails[j].quantity;
            console.log("onchange - to ensure that the quantity variable always contains a number------>",quantity);


            individualQty = parseInt(individualQty) + parseInt(quantity);
            console.log("onchange - to sum up the individual quantities for each selected address within a POS item------>",individualQty);

            posItemsListWithCart[i].selectedAddressWithQtyDetails[j].quantity = parseInt(quantity);
            console.log("onchange - assigning the parser integer value --------->",posItemsListWithCart[i].selectedAddressWithQtyDetails[j].quantity)

        }
        posItemsListWithCart[i].totalQuantityFromAllAddresses = individualQty;
        console.log('onchange - asssigning parsed integer value to the totalQuantityFromAllAddresses container--------->',posItemsListWithCart[i].totalQuantityFromAllAddresses)

        // to check if the total quntity is less than current available stock
        if (posItemsListWithCart[i].totalQuantityFromAllAddresses <= currentAvailableStock) {
            posItemsListWithCart[i].isAvailableQuantityExceeded = false;

        } else {
            posItemsListWithCart[i].isAvailableQuantityExceeded = true;
            this.disablePreview = true;

        }

    }

    this.posItemsListInCart = posItemsListWithCart;
    console.log("onchange - this.posItemsListInCart ---------->",JSON.stringify(this.posItemsListInCart))
    // to send the updated quntity ot the apex method "updateQuantityForSelectedPosItem" with the parameter positemid,shipping address id and order id and quntity added.
    updateQuantityForSelectedPosItem({
        posItemId: this.posItemId,
        shippingAddressId: this.shippingAddressId,
        orderId: this.orderId,
        quantity: this.quantityUpdateValue
    })
        .then(result => {
            // once the quntity is sent to the apex method the result should be sent as 'done'
            let resultObtained = result;
            // console.log("resultObtained ---------> ",resultObtained)
            return refreshApex(this.cartItemsToBeDisplayed);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            //console.log('ERROR', this.error);
        });
}`

`get cartItemDetails() {
    // To get the pos items in cart to display
    if (this.cartItemsToBeDisplayed.data) {
        console.log('onload START - inside if')
        console.log("onload - after updating this.cartItemsToBeDisplayed.data",JSON.stringify(this.cartItemsToBeDisplayed.data))
        // console.log('cartItemsToBeDisplayed-->', JSON.stringify(this.cartItemsToBeDisplayed.data))

        this.posItemsListInCart = this.cartItemsToBeDisplayed.data;
        // console.log("onload - hold the updated data in the this.posItemsListInCart continer ",JSON.stringify(this.posItemsListInCart))

        //To check if the given pos item has the data or not 
        if (this.posItemsListInCart.length > 0) {
            // console.log('onload - inside if 1 ')
            // console.log("onload - check the length -------->",this.posItemsListInCart.length)
            this.isAddressAvailableForDisplay = true;
            // console.log("onload - this.isAddressAvailableForDisplay is true -------->",this.isAddressAvailableForDisplay)
        } else {
            this.isAddressAvailableForDisplay = false;
            // console.log("onload - this.isAddressAvailableForDisplay is false -------->",this.isAddressAvailableForDisplay)
        }
        // to assign the total quanity to zero by default
        this.totalQuantity = 0;
        // if total quntity is 0 then disable the preview button
        this.disablePreview = true;
        // local variable to convert the pos items in cart to json parse so that anyone can edit the incoming items
        var posItemsListWithCart = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.posItemsListInCart));
        // console.log("onload - local variable to convert the pos items in cart to json parse posItemsListWithCart -------->",JSON.stringify(this.isAddressAvailableForDisplay))

        var isAvailableQuantityExceeded = false;

        //to check if the entred quantity has exceed initally
        for (var i = 0; i < posItemsListWithCart.length; i++) {
            // console.log('inside for loop--------->')

            this.totalQuantity += this.posItemsListInCart[i].totalQuantityFromAllAddresses;
            // console.log('onload  - increments this.totalQuantity--------->',this.totalQuantity)

            var individualQty = 0;
            // Author: Shilpa and Kavya
            // Date: 19-12-2023
            // To get the Logical_Inventory__c from POS_Item_Facilities__r
            for(var z=0;z<posItemsListWithCart[i].posItem.POS_Item_Facilities__r.length;z++){
                // console.log('inside for loop 1')

            //local variable to store thhe logical inventory stock
            var currentAvailableStock = posItemsListWithCart[i].posItem.POS_Item_Facilities__r[z].Logical_Inventory__c;
            // console.log("onload - currentAvailableStock",currentAvailableStock)
            }
            // Changes done upto here
            //console.log('currentAvailableStock',currentAvailableStock)
            // to check if any item in cart has a quanity entred greater than available stock
            for (var j = 0; j < posItemsListWithCart[i].selectedAddressWithQtyDetails.length; j++) {
                // console.log('onload  - inside for loop 2')

                var quantity = posItemsListWithCart[i].selectedAddressWithQtyDetails[j].quantity == '' ? 0 : posItemsListWithCart[i].selectedAddressWithQtyDetails[j].quantity;
                // console.log('onload - quantity -------->',quantity)

                individualQty = parseInt(individualQty) + parseInt(quantity);
                // console.log('onload - individualQty -------->',individualQty)

                posItemsListWithCart[i].selectedAddressWithQtyDetails[j].quantity = parseInt(quantity);
                // console.log('onload - posItemsListWithCart[i].selectedAddressWithQtyDetails[j].quantity -------->',posItemsListWithCart[i].selectedAddressWithQtyDetails[j].quantity)
            }
            posItemsListWithCart[i].totalQuantityFromAllAddresses = individualQty;
            // console.log('onload - posItemsListWithCart[i].totalQuantityFromAllAddresses -------->',posItemsListWithCart[i].totalQuantityFromAllAddresses)
            //if exceded then disable the preview button
            //to display error message
            if (posItemsListWithCart[i].totalQuantityFromAllAddresses <= currentAvailableStock) {
                posItemsListWithCart[i].isAvailableQuantityExceeded = false;

            } else {
                posItemsListWithCart[i].isAvailableQuantityExceeded = true;
                isAvailableQuantityExceeded = true;

            }

        }
        this.posItemsListInCart = posItemsListWithCart;
        // console.log('onload - this.posItemsListInCart -------->',JSON.stringify(this.posItemsListInCart))
        
        this.cartItemsToBeDisplayed.data = posItemsListWithCart;
        // console.log('onload END - this.cartItemsToBeDisplayed.data -------->',JSON.stringify(this.cartItemsToBeDisplayed.data))

        // if quntity is > 0 then enable the repview button
        if (this.totalQuantity > 0) {
            this.disablePreview = false;
        }
        // if quntity is = 0 then the repview button is disabled with the help of the variable "disablePreview"
        if (this.totalQuantity == 0 || isAvailableQuantityExceeded) {
            this.disablePreview = true;
        }
        if (this.posItemsListInCart.length > 0) {
            if (this.posItemsListInCart[0].orderId) {
                this.orderId = this.posItemsListInCart[0].orderId;
            }
        }
        /**
    refreshApex(this.cartItemsToBeDisplayed);
}`


Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your questions as code). Please edit your question and add the explanation.
Also please read how do I ask a good question. You'll get better answers if you follow this guidance.
